# not all values in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a scatterplot wiht ggplot, but it doesn't show all values. In this plot should be over 200 points and yet it has just around 30 points. I think that they lie on top of each other. Thus, I would like to change the size of the points. Values which can be found many times should be larger than values which can be found only a few times. I don't know how to do this and unfortunately, I can't find a solution on the internet. I hope that someone can help me. Thank you!
This is my skript:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input1 <- "C:\\Users\\heading_winddirection.csv"

heading_winddirection <- read.csv(input1, sep=";")
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
dput(heading_winddirection)

plot <-ggplot(heading_winddirection, aes(x=as.character(winddirection), y=as.character(heading))) + geom_point(stat="identity") + geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=FALSE)
plot <-plot +theme(legend.position="none") + theme_bw()+
 scale_y_discrete(labels=c("1" = "North", "2" = "North East", "3" = "East", "4"= "South East", "5"= "South", "6"="South West", "7"="West", "8"="North West"))+
 scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "North", "2" = "North East", "3" = "East", "4"= "South East", "5"= "South", "6"="South West", "7"="West", "8"="North West"))

print(plot)
```

My Data

```
structure(list(heading = c(1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
  3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
  1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
  1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
  5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
  5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
  7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
  5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
  5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
  5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
  1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
  2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L), winddirection = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
  8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 
  2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
  3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
  2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
  7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
  2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
  8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
  6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
  5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
  5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
  4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -224L))
```

Comment: Please provide your data with `dput()` function.

Comment: @PawełChabros OP provides data using `dput`

Comment: You have to add `position_jitter` in `geom_point` - e.g.  `geom_point(position = position_jitter(.1))`

Comment: You can also use `alpha` like, `geom_point(stat="identity", alpha=0.5)`. See `?geom_point`

Comment: Thank you @Pawel Chabros. position_ jitter is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do an intermediate step before the plot like below

```
libarary(dplyr)
heading_winddirection %>% group_by(winddirection,heading) %>% mutate(n=n()) -> heading_winddirection
```

Then

```
... + geom_point(stat="identity",aes(size=n)) + ...
```